# Multi-dimensional input in Keras.js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, keras

I am looking to implement my Keras model into my website with the [Keras.js](https://transcranial.github.io/keras-js/#/) library. One problem with this library is that when inputting data in javascript, only a Float32Array() is allowed as an input. This type of array is 1D, and in my Keras model, the input is 3D. I have asked on the [Keras.js issues page](https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js/issues/37) and found some potential solutions such as adding an embedding layer, but that requires a specific input shape, but I would like to have any 3D input work, as it did when I trained the model. The model structure is simple, there is an input layer which takes an array of dimension mxnx3 (it is an image of unknown size with r, g, and b channels) and a Conv2D layer, which then outputs an mxnx1 array. I know the model works because it can give a good output based on an input, so the only problem I have is with the transition to Keras.js. Here is the JS code that I have at the moment.

```
function predictImageWithCNN(data) { //'data' is mxnx3 array
  var final = [];
  //instantiating model from json and buf files
  var model = new KerasJS.Model({
    filepaths: {
      model: 'dist/model.json',
      weights: 'dist/model_weights.buf',
      metadata: 'dist/model_metadata.json'
    },
    gpu: true //MAY NEED TO CHANGE (NOT SURE REALLY)
 });

  //Ready the model.
  model.ready()
  .then(function() {
    //This matches our input data with the input key (b/c Sequential Model)
    var inputData = {
      'input_1': new Float32Array(data)
    };
    // make predictions based on inputData
    return model.predict(inputData);
  })
  .then(function(outputData) {
   //Here we take the outputData and parse it to get a result.

    var out = outputData['output']; //Gets output data

    console.log(out);
    //TODO: Put in code to assign outputData to 'final' so we can then convert it
    //      This should not be too hard to do.

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // handle error
  });
  return final; // should return nxmx1 array of vals 0-1.
}
```

If anyone had any suggestions for how to resolve this, that would be very much appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried to just pass the input data in anyway? I suspect it does not care about dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an `LSTM`. The way I got around this was by training using a flattened version of the data but using a reshape layer as the first layer to get it to the shape I needed for my `LSTM`. eg.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((40,59),input_shape=(1,2360)))
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))
model.add(Dense(len(chars)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

Then in `Keras.JS` I can feed in the flattened version from `Float32Array`